# Java Regex doesn't match although debug tools do

Tags: java, regex

I have written a regular expression to parse strings of the format

OBJECT_NAME KEY1=value KEY2=value

(actually done by 2 regexps)

This is my utils class:

```
package de.hs.settlers.util;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ParseUtils {
    public static final Pattern OBJECT_NAME_PATTERN = 
            Pattern.compile("^([A-Z0-9 ]+) ([A-Z]+=.+)$");
    public static final Pattern KEY_VALUE_PATTERN = 
            Pattern.compile("^([A-Z0-9]+)=([^=]+)( [A-Z]+=.+)?$");

    public static ParseResult parseKeyValueLine(String line) {
        Matcher object = OBJECT_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(line.trim());
        String objectName = object.group(1);
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String vals = object.group(2);
        do {
            Matcher matcher = KEY_VALUE_PATTERN.matcher(vals);

            if (!matcher.matches()) {
                break;
            }

            String key = matcher.group(1);
            String value = matcher.group(2);
            data.put(key, value);
            vals = matcher.group(3);
            if (vals != null) {
                vals = vals.trim();
            }
        } while (vals != null);

        return new ParseResult(objectName, data);
    }

    public static class ParseResult {
        private String objectName;
        private HashMap<String, String> data;

        public ParseResult(String objectName, HashMap<String, String> data) {
            super();
            this.objectName = objectName;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public String getObjectName() {
            return objectName;
        }

        public HashMap<String, String> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public String get(String key) {
            return getData().get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

I've written a test that tests the method parseKeyValueLine with "USER TEAM=Team A USER=tuxitux OTHER=bla" as the line argument, but the execution fails because the first expression (the one in OBJECT_NAME_PATTERN) apparenly didn't match.

The problem I have is that when I paste the expression and the string to test it with into regex debuggers, they all tell me it matches and give me the correct groups. (tested with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and http://www.debuggex.com/).

Is there anything wrong with how java does regular expressions?

Comment: I can't see an underscore in your RE pattern

Comment: @Izzy the underscores get matched by ([^=]+), which means "one or more characters which are not '='".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Matcher object = OBJECT_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(line.trim());
String objectName = object.group(1);
```

You created the matcher, but you didn't tell it to actually do its work on the string. As a result, even if there was a match you'd have no groups available.

You need to call one of the matching methods (`.find()`, `.lookingAt()` or `.matches()`, but all three will be equivalent for you since your regexes are anchored both at the beginning and end of input), *and then* collect the groups.

Example (`.find()`):

```
Matcher object = OBJECT_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(line.trim());
object.find(); // or you could have an if statement here
String objectName = object.group(1);
```

Comment: +1: Your answer is correct. I took the liberty of adding an example. If you don't agree, roll it back, I obviously won't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have any watch expressions. For me it was the IDE watch expressions which caused the issue.